# Is this a bug in bash when editing command line in editor through vi, or expected behavior?

Tags: bash, vim, vi, cd

I have this setting in my `~/.inputrc` file:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

but the behavior is the same if I have

```
set -o vi
```

in `~/.bashrc. In addition I also have

```
export VISUAL=vim
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"
```

in the latter file.

The buggy behavior I observed is reproducible as follows:

1. fill the command line with a valid change directory command, e.g. `cd existingFolder`,
2. press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to exit insert mode and enter normal mode,
3. press <kbd>v</kbd> to open `vi`/`vim`,
4. accept the command by <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Result: the current directory has changed, but the prompt, if it shows the currect directory, has not updated to reflect the change of it.

Is this a bug or an expected behavior?

A screencast is better than a thousand words:

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens independently of `vim`, `vi`, or bash's `vi` mode.

A MCVE is this:

```
$ cd /usr && env -i EDITOR='touch' PS1='\w \$ ' bash --norc
/usr $ cd bin   # press Ctrl-X Ctrl-E instead of Enter here
cd bin
/usr $ pwd      # Bug visible here, prompt should say `/usr/bin`
/usr/bin
/usr/bin $      # Prompt now showing expected value
```

The prompt fails to update, and `PROMPT_COMMAND` is not executed. Upstream git commit [6c6454cb1](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/?id=6c6454cb18d7cd30b3b26d5ba6479431e599f3ed) from 2020-02-07 shows the same behavior.

So to answer the question, yup, looks like a bug.